# Does kinetic energy of rotation depend upon the reference point chosen?

Tags: energy, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Consider a particle moving in a straight line. The translational kinetic energy of the particle is given by $mv^2/2$. If we assume the reference point to be any point which does not lie on the path of the particle, shouldn't we get a rotational kinetic energy of the particle too in addition to the translational kinetic energy as the angle made by the particle chosen point changes and therefore an angular velocity exists?

Comment: I couldn't quite get this assumption, please explain "reference point to be any point which does not lie on the path of the particle"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A point can have angular velocity but the kinetic energy is still translational. Same as for circular motion.
You can write the kinetic energy for a point-like object undergoing circular motion as $ \frac{1}{2} mv^2 $ or $ \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 R^2 $ but you get the same thing. They are not different contribution to kinetic energy.
The term "rotational kinetic energy" refers usualy to the rotation of an object which is not point-like. Even in this case, there is just one kinetic energy which is the sum of the kinetics energies of the particles making the object. It is a convenient concept to split it into two terms, translation of center of mass and roattion around the center of mass.
The KE depends on the motion of the reference frame used to define it. But not on a reference point you choose in this frame. There is no reference point for KE. Just reference frame.